# Footer not 'always' sticking to the bottom

Tags: html, css, footer, zen

The footer of this web page I'm working on is sticking to the bottom on most pages, except when the content is larger than it's "supposed to be".

A faulty page is: *
A good page is: *

I tried multiple methods of sticking the footer at the bottom, all with different results.

This is the Zen starterkit-template from Drupal 7.x.

Comment: remove `height` from `wrapper`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the footer. You have this CSS that forces a height of 1100px on the `#wrapper` and `#subwrapper` elements, which is why it seems like there's something "below" the footer.

```
#wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 240px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1100px; /* This is making the page longer than it should be.*/
  background: #85bb99;
  z-index: -5;
}

#wrapper #subwrapper {
  background: url('/themeimages/pattern-cutout.png');
  opacity: 0.2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1100px; /* Same thing here */
}
```

It looks like you're using these elements as a background image. You can fix it by trying this CSS instead:

```
#wrapper{
  position: fixed; /* Use fixed positioning so it'll always be displayed */
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* Set a height of 100% */
  background: #85bb99;
  z-index: -5;
}

#wrapper #subwrapper {
  background: url('/themeimages/pattern-cutout.png');
  opacity: 0.2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* Set a height of 100% */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is part of the solution.
The background starts at 240px, so the top 240px are white, because I changed it to fixed it will scroll along. It's supposed to fill the background from 240px from the top downwards.

So the problem with the footer is fixed, but it creates another problem.

Comment: Problem is solved by making a header-white DIV, now the position: fixed; background is filling the whole background with a z-index of -5, the header page is -1, the rest is 0.